# How to remove empty rows in xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem with my code.
I use this function to remove row, which has empty cell( the cell has index of numCell). The java.lang.NullPointerException error happened when i tried to run this function.

My code:

```
static void RemoveEmptyRow(XSSFSheet mySheet, int numCell) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int rownum = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
        Row currentRow = mySheet.getRow(i);
        Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(numCell);
        if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK || cell.getStringCellValue().equals("")) //cell == null || 
        {
            mySheet.removeRow(currentRow);
            int lastRowIndex = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
            if (i >= 0 && i < lastRowIndex) {
                mySheet.shiftRows(i + 1,lastRowIndex, -1);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly are the issues while using your code?

Comment: http://affy.blogspot.in/2004/04/poi-optimization-eliminating-trailing.html refer this link

Comment: I have a xlsx file. I use this function to remove rows, which has empty cell( the cell has index of numCell). The java.lang.NullPointerException error happened when i tried to run this function. Pls!

Comment: "The java.lang.NullPointerException error happened": You should learn to debug. Java provides stack traces which explicitly points to the code line where the error occurs. After you are knowing this, check the parameters around this code line. I suspect the erroneous code line is `Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(numCell);` and `currentRow` is null. So do check what is `i` in `Row currentRow = mySheet.getRow(i);` if the error occurs. Hint: Since you are removing rows, this will influence the for-loop using `rownum ` as the upper bound of `i`.